# mySQL Subquery - Single pass if possible

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am looking to perform a query that will return data from a number of tables in mySQL that will require some subqueries however I am not sure if what I am trying to achieve is even possible in a single pass.

I have the below as an example (i know this doesn't work but gives you the idea)

```
SELECT field_id, field_1, 
  (SELECT subfield_1 FROM tableb WHERE subfield_id = field_3) AS field_a, 
  (SELECT subfield_1 FROM tableb WHERE subfield_id = field_4) as field_b 
FROM tablea WHERE field_2 = 123
```

This will pull 2 entries from a second table based on 2 different columns in the primary table.

```
tablea
----------
field_id, bigint
field_1, varchar(50)
field_2, int
field_3, bigint
field_4, bigint

tableb
----------
subfield_id, bigint
subfield_1, varchar(50)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN`s. Depending on whether `field_3` and `field_4` are `NULL`able or not use either `LEFT JOIN` (as in example below) or `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT field_id, field_1, b1.subfield_1 field_a, b2.subfield_1 field_b
  FROM tablea a LEFT JOIN tableb b1 
    ON a.field_3 = b1.subfield_id LEFT JOIN tableb b2
    ON a.field_4 = b2.subfield_id
 WHERE a.field_2 = 123
```

Sample output:

```
| FIELD_ID | FIELD_1 |   FIELD_A |   FIELD_B |
|----------|---------|-----------|-----------|
|        1 |      11 | subvalue1 | subvalue5 |
|        2 |      22 | subvalue4 | subvalue2 |
|        3 |      33 | subvalue2 |    (null) |
```

**Note:** Make sure that you have indices on `field_3` and `field_4`

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/75c78/1)** demo

Comment: @user2843145 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is possible only if your sub query returns one row .
for example here

```
    (SELECT subfield_1 FROM tableb     WHERE subfield_id = field_3)
```

field 3 should be a primary key for tableb

Answer (score 0):

You could perform an `outer join`, where you will see the same result without having the delay of having to use a `correlated subquery`.

The outer join has the advantage that all rows from `tablea` will be displayed, regardless of whether there is an accompanying value within the `tableb` subqueries.

A normal join would instead only return rows where all three tables contained `field_3` and `field_4`, and as a result the row for field_id = 3 would not be returned.

**Example:**

```
SELECT field_id,
       field_1,
       s1.subfield_1 as field_a,
       s2.subfield_1 as field_b
FROM tablea AS a
LEFT JOIN tableb AS s1 ON a.field_3 = s1.subfield_id
LEFT JOIN tableb AS s2 ON a.field_4 = s2.subfield_id
WHERE field_2 = 123;
```